# Visual Studio 2010 Build - exits with code -1073741502 (0xc0000142) after VS2012 installation. Maybe due to dll symbols?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll, crash, debug-symbols

I'm writing a game (with Angel engine) in Visual C++ Express 2010, and even after commenting out everything in main, the program crashes on startup (the application was unable to start correctly). This started happening after installing VS2012. I have tried restarting, rebuilding, using Release and Debug, running VS as Administrator etc.

Initially I had to put this into the Post-Build Event Command Line to get it to compile:

```
    @echo off
    echo Copying $(OutDir)$(TargetName)$(TargetExt) as $(TargetName)D$(TargetExt)
    copy /Y $(OutDir)$(TargetName)$(TargetExt) $(OutDir)$(TargetName)D$(TargetExt)
```

It used to not find the PDB files correctly, but I turned on Microsoft Symbol Servers for the .pdb locations and gave it a cache directory. Now, the Debug output says:

```
    'ClientGame.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
```

with about 20 different dlls, most of which looking like standard windows things, and opengl. A few don't have "source information stripped" after them. A few say this:

```
    'ClientGame.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\devil.dll', Binary was not built with debug information
```

In Solution output, I get:

```
    directorytoproject\Libraries\libogg-        1.3.0\win32\VS2008\libogg_static.vcxproj : warning  : Platform 'x64' referenced in the project file         '_libogg' cannot be found. Please make sure you have it installed under         '%VCTargetsPath%\Platforms\x64'.
```

with a couple of other libraries as well.

Runtime library setting is on "Multi-threaded Debug DLL (/MDd)"

I would really appreciate any ideas! Thanks a lot!